# Picasso is just working on one emulator

Tags: android, picasso

I can load my image succeed on a emulator `(Android 7.0 API24)`

I use Picasso version is

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

When i run project to another emulator on other computer or my android device that is Huaweb mate8(`Android 7.0 API24`), i can't load my image anymore, it shows error image.

I don't know why it happens like this.

Here is my imageUrl="`http://192.168.22.111:2212/DB/Convention/1.jpg`"
Any emulators and my android device use the same WIFI.

My code:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).centerCrop().fit()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.button_icon_apply_128x128)
                    .error(R.drawable.app_icon_512x512)
                    .into(destImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: TRUE");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onError: TRUE");
                        }
                    });
```

My imageView xml:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/destImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your test device was connected on internet (Or your private network)? Run web browser for check it.

Your emulator can use your PC's network, instead of using real wifi.

Load your URL With web browser in your device.

Comment: Yes , i test imageUrl on other computer , i find the problem now. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: How did you solve it? Could you tell me which IP address you use?http://10.0.2.2 for emulator right?

Comment: @swiftlearneer You don't need to set your IP address. All you need to do is create a new emulator with latest OS. Then, android studio will setup your emulator properly. In the emulator, you can find "Android wifi - connected" from the top of the screen.